# Obtener ultimo registro por código(Sin repetir) en Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
select distinct S.Semana, V.Codigo, Max(V.Fecha) as Fecha 
FROM Visitas V 
left join CSemanas S ON V.Fecha between S.Inicio and S.Fin 
group by S.Semana, V.Codigo
```

La cual me da el siguiente resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo que necesito es que me muestre el ultimo registro por código de la fecha mas reciente, es decir no quiero que se repitan los códigos. Por ejemplo como se ve, se repite el código 01743 y el 02834 de ellos solo quiero el registro mas reciente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y la semana? cual quereS? porque si sacas ese campo vas a tener exactamente lo que queres

Comment: si lose, pero necesito el campo Semana para otras operaciones @gbianchi

Comment: aja.. y porque no sacarlo de este query.. y al resultado de tu nuevo query, hacerle un join a la misma tabla y solo traer de esa la semana.. uniendo por codigo y fecha... ;)... es como la solucion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes obtener el resultado que quieres usando ROW_NUMBER() para numerar las filas y posteriormente seleccionar unas en concreto.

He usado los siguientes datos para simular el resultado de tu consulta:

```
create table t (Semana int, Codigo int, Fecha date);
insert into t values
(01, 100, '20190101'),
(02, 100, '20190108'),
(01, 200, '20190101'),
(02, 200, '20190108');
```

Basta con usar tu query en una consulta CTE o como un sub-query y seleccionar los registros con row_number = 1.

```
with ct as
(
select distinct 
    Semana, Codigo, Fecha,
    row_number() over (partition by Codigo order by Fecha desc) rn
from
    t
)
select
    Semana, Codigo, Fecha
from
    ct
where
   rn = 1;
```

Este es el resultado:

```
Semana | Codigo | Fecha              
-----: | -----: | :------------------
     2 |    100 | 08/01/2019 00:00:00
     2 |    200 | 08/01/2019 00:00:00
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f58d3147dd4be6130f4fc1cf2bf80d76)*